# Clean install of 14.04 gives endless "Wrong Mac address"

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel

I booted my laptop with a USB with Ubuntu 14.04, and verified that 14.04 is working fine, and my internal drive is intact and working.  Then I hit install.

The install program worked the first couple steps, but is now hanging forever on "Detecting file systems..."

And the screen is printing over and over again the following:

Sep  3 11:38:08 ubuntu kernel: [10317.912522] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Wrong Mac address

This has been going on over an hour.

A bit of history: previously I tried to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04, but in the middle of this upgrade I lost power.  Then tried to resume the upgrade using various methods unsuccessfully, finally deciding just to back up everything and do a clean install.  This clean install is now hanging as above.

Any ideas what to do next?
Thanks,
Stew

Comment: Re-install your broadcom driver. Oh and it is a bug in (a or some of ) the driver(s) made by broadcom: https://bugs.mageia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3296

Comment: Thanks.  Can you explain how to do this?  I'm guessing I'll need to somehow escape from the 14.04 installation first?

Comment: The answer below looks correct to me :)

Answer (score 1):

I advise you backup all useful files to other usb disk, and then use the usb boot system to clean disk partition table using terminal command "sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1 count=512"
and after this action, reboot and try your installation again

Comment: Thanks Bill.  I'll just escape the installation now by shutting down and rebooting on the USB, and follow your instructions.